# send_mass_mail in background django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am using send_mass_email to send emails to a list of users. It is working fine until I send it to more than 200 emails at a time.
Actually emails are being delivered without a problem. But I am getting time-out error from nginx because it takes long( more than 2 mins) to send emails to all 200+ emails.

What is the best way to run send_mass_mail in background ?

Comment: @heltonbiker spam ?? you mean the post ?? If you mean the post , it is not. Now that I have got so many responses , I will try to go through the solutions . Thanks everyone for the responses .

Comment: no, no, I was just kidding about the association between mass-email and spam, but of course there are other (useful) uses for mass-email. Sorry to "spam" your question ;o)

Answer (score 3):

You need to move the tasks to the background (so they don't block the web process). One of the most popular ways to do this is to use a messaging/task queue.

[Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) is one of the most popular distributed task queues, and coupled with the [django-celery](http://ask.github.com/django-celery/) application makes this trivial.

First you need to setup celery (which is as simple as `pip install -U celery`); and one of the many messaging brokers that it supports. The most popular one is [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html); but for quick and dirty set ups you can also use your [existing database](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/otherqueues.html#django-database) as a message broker.

Finally, since this is a common problem solved by celery+django, there is [django-celery-email](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery-email) which takes care of the rest.

Comment: Celery is a good choice when you're going to have lots of moving parts in the background, but for something simple like asynchronously sending email, it's overkill. If this is all you need to do in the background, just fire off a thread.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into the [django-mailer](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-mailer-2) project, which encapsulates this functionality - it does this via crons, rather than using a task queue. I've been using it for a while with good results.

Comment: I am getting ImportError: No module named django_mailer error even after following the instructions at https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-mailer-2/blob/master/docs/install.txt

Comment: After putting django after other apps in installed_app list, I am not getting the error. 
But I am using send_mass_mail no send_mail , but it seems I cannot import from django_mailer import send_mass_mail .

Answer (score 1):

You can send mails in separate thread, for example:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=send_mass_email,
            args=[messages],
            kwargs={'fail_silently': True})
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()
```

or just use cron and django management commands =)
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: It is not a good idea to spawn threads in web applications like this.

Comment: I can send mas_email in a different thread and it is running in the background properly. But the problem is that it is talking too long to send those emails . Before I couldn't send more than 200 emails. But now to send even those 200 email it is taking way too long. I am using sendgrid and it is taking in avg 6 mins to send one mail.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a management command and then setup a periodic cron job to send out  the emails refer [management command docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/)